# Estimating raw and standardized variance with umx package in R

Tags: r

I want to estimate the raw and standardized variance of performance IQ, with SES as moderator.

```
> head(PIQ)
  zyg SES1 SES2 PIQ1 PIQ2
1   1    3    3   78   93
2   1    4    4   95   92
3   1    2    2  115  109
4   1    1    1  119  101
5   1    3    3   91   89
6   1    2    2  102  100
```

I fit the model with SES as moderator with the umx package with this line of code:

```
ACE_PIQ = umxGxE(selDVs = "PIQ", selDefs = "SES", sep = "",
            dzData = PIQMZ, mzData = PIQDZ, dropMissing = TRUE)

summary(ACE_PIQ)
```

Then, I remove the e*m parameter:

```
ACE_PIQ_noE = umxModify(ACE_PIQ, regex=c("em_r1c1"), free=F, name='ACE_PIQ_noE')
umxCompare(ACE_PIQ, ACE_PIQ_noE)
```

Of this model, I want to report the raw and standardized variance. I have been getting the raw estimates with this line of code, but for some reason, I dont get a 2x2 matrix this time, but only 1x1. Can anyone help me with this?

```
est_SigmaA=ACE_PIQ_noE$submodels$top$algebras$A$result
est_RA=cov2cor(est_SigmaA)
```

The result I get back looks like this:

```
> print(est_SigmaA)
             [,1]
[1,] 1.414617e-12

> print(est_RA)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
```

But it is supposed to look like this (but different numbers):

```
print(est_SigmaA)
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 2.446946 2.024482
[2,] 2.024482 3.488346

print(est_RA)
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.6929339
[2,] 0.6929339 1.0000000
```

Does anyone know why it suddenly gives me a 1x1 matrix rather than 2x2?

Comment: Your table is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: How should I do it? By using | ---- |  ?

Comment: Find out [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357693/how-to-create-a-table-in-my-question).